# printf in microblaze for hex to char

Tags: c, printf, xilinx, microblaze

I am trying `xil_printf()` inside a for loop and feeding it to a SendBuffer over uart. 
How can print the characters instead of integers ? All it is printing is hex number...

```
uint32_t IRAM;
for(Index=0; Index<tsize; Index++){
  int sb = Index*sizeof(uint32_t);
  IRAM = XIo_In32(RAMADD+sb);
  xil_printf("Data: %08x\n\r",IRAM);
}
```

This prints hex charaters:

```
Data: 00004241
Data: 00004443
Data: 00004645
Data: 00004847
```

I tried :

```
xil_printf("Data: %08c\n\r",IRAM)
```

and it prints single characters :

```
Data: A
Data: C
```

How can I print the the following (converting hex charaters 4241 to AB, 4443 to CD etc...) ?

```
Data: AB
Data: CD
```

Comment: Please clarify your question: "How can I print the 16 ?" - what do you want to print?

Comment: added clarification ! Why the negative vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to print two bytes/characters, so you can specify it explicitly in the format string:

```
xil_printf("Data: %c%c\n\r", char1, char2);
```

But first you need to calculate the bytes to print. For example:

```
int char1 = (IRAM >> 8) & 0xff;
int char2 = IRAM & 0xff;
```

(possibly switch char1 <-> char2; I am not sure about what order you want to print them in)

Comment: genius. that works... Can you explain the `IRAM >> 8` ? This shifts by 1-byte getting the next char, correct ?

Comment: @chickegg Yes; but you should be careful to avoid confusion about what is "next" char. Your definition of "next" is the little-endian one. According to big-endian ordering, the other byte (`xxx >> 0`) is the "next" one. Names like "more significant" and "less significant" are not ambiguous in this way.